# Epoll не до конца читает данные из сокета

Tags: c++, linux, epoll

```
while(true)
{
    int nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);

        if (nfds == -1) 
        std::cout << "[ERROR] nfds error" << std::endl;


    for (size_t k = 0; k < nfds; ++k)
    {
        if(events[k].data.fd == sock)
        {            
            listen_res = listen(events[k].data.fd, 1);

            if(listen_res = 1)
                    {
                connection = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &len); 

                if(connection == -1)
                    continue;

                if (setnonblocking(connection) == -1)
                    std::cout << "[ERROR] setnonblocking()" << std::endl;


                ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLERR | EPOLLET;
                ev.data.fd = connection;


                if(epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, connection, &ev) == -1)
                                std::cout << "[ERROR] epoll_ctl(connection) returned an error " << std::endl;
                else
                    std::cout << "[INFO] New Client's IP: " << inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr) << std::endl;


            }

        }
        else
        {



            if (events[k].events & (EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLHUP))
            {
                std::cout << "Disconnect" << std::endl;

                ThreadPool.add(task);

                close(events[k].data.fd);
                epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[k].data.fd, &ev);

            }
            else if (events[k].events & EPOLLIN)
            {


                do
                {
                    read(events[k].data.fd, &Packet, sizeof(PacketStructure));
                    do_work(&Packet);

                }while(errno != EAGAIN);


                }


            }






    }







}
```

После определенного количества посланных пакетов (отправляю части файла размером по 128 байт) этот код перестает принимать пакеты от клиента.
Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: тут ошибки нет, подразумевая, что сокет неблокирующий, так что больше кода в студию... а лучше сразу [mcve].

Comment: @Fat-Zer , сокеты использую неблокирующие и epoll edge-triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> do {
>   read(events[k].data.fd, &Packet, sizeof(PacketStructure));
>   do_work(&Packet);
> } while(errno != EAGAIN);
> ```

Скорей всего проблема в том, что перед вызовом `read()` для такой проверки `errno` нужно обнулять вручную т.к. `read()` как и ни один другой системный вызов этого не делает. В итоге все исполнения цикла кроме первого обрабатывают ровно один пакет, а когда возникает ситуация, что `epoll_wait()` возвращает сокет в котором готово два пакета на считывание, при ещё одном вызове `epoll_wait()` всё виснет.

Можно также изменить условие на что-то вроде:

```
 ssize_t read_rv;
 do {
   read_rv = read(events[k].data.fd, &Packet, sizeof(PacketStructure));
   do_work(&Packet);
 } while(read_rv >= 0 && errno != EAGAIN);
 errno=0;
```

Также из плохого/подозрительного в приведённом куске:

- У `read`'а должен быть контроль ошибок т.к. в противном случае вероятен вечный цикл.
- Вообще говоря, `read()` из tcp-сокета может корректно вернуть любое количество данных (от одного байта до `sizeof(PacketStructure)`). Соответственно при обработке пакета это надо учитывать...
- Передавать `sizeof(PacketStructure)` `read`'у не самая лучшая идея т.к. размер многих типов данных архитектурно зависимый... Не говоря уже о порядке байт.
- Как говорит тётя маня `EPOLLERR`, в `epoll_ctl` явно передавать не обязательно. А вот обрабатывать — желательно.